# CSS3 Background-size Firefox Bug? Not working but VISIBLE in Firebug - Firefox 3.6

Tags: html, firefox, css

I'm using the new CSS3 spec "background-size" to have a background image that slightly overflows the size of the page.  It's working fine in webkit (Chrome & Safari) but the "-moz-background-size" property is not working at all in Firefox. The unusual thing is, if you view the site live, the "-moz-background-size" property **IS** showing when viewing the site with Firebug! The FF docs say that it is supported as of 3.6 and I'm running 3.6.

The production version of the site: http://anasmadance.com.s66112.gridserver.com/

Here's my code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1150px) { 
/* special sytles for browser windows less than 1150px */
body{
 -o-background-size: 130%; -webkit-background-size: 130%; -khtml-background-size: 130%; -moz-background-size: 130%;
 background-size: 130%;
}
#trans_fake{
 -o-background-size: 130%; -webkit-background-size: 130%; -khtml-background-size: 130%; -moz-background-size: 130%; 
 background-size: 130%;
}
}
```

Any debug suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quickly tried to add the `!important` directive via firebug and it seems to work:

```
-moz-background-size: 130% auto !important;
```

But I can't understand what is overriding. I found you placed the -moz specific vendor propriety after the standard one, try to invert this. Just a guess.

Comment: I think it's because `-moz-background-size` on `body` is getting overridden by the more specific `.page-id-7, .... { background:url("images/bg-beach.jpg") no-repeat fixed center top #000000 }`.